# Time evolution of monitored quantum dynamics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, measurements, time-evolution, quantum-measurements

Let us assume that the quantum system consists of Hilbert space $H$ with basis vectors $|i\rangle$. The initial state $|\Psi(0)\rangle$ evolves in discrete time steps such that $|\Psi(t+\delta t) \rangle = U|\Psi(t)\rangle$.

Furthermore, I assume that each unitary operator is followed by a projective measurement with the probability of taking the measurement being $p$. Under the measurement

$$|\Psi(t)\rangle \rightarrow \frac{M_i|\Psi(t)\rangle }{\lVert M_i |\Psi(t)\rangle\rVert}$$
where $M_i = |i\rangle\langle i|$ occurs with probability $p_i = \langle \Psi(t)|M^\dagger_iM_i|\Psi(t)\rangle$.

I take many ensembles with a fixed initial state and take the average over $p$.

I'm interested in the evolution of such a system. In particular, how do I describe such a monitored system. Should I write the density matrix evolution --

$$\rho(t) = (1-p)  |\Psi(t)\rangle \langle \Psi(t)| + p\ \frac{M_i|\Psi(t)\rangle }{\lVert M_i |\Psi(t)\rangle\rVert} $$

Can someone help me with this. I'm trying to start some analytics but not sure.

Comment: Do you want to study the Quantum-Zeno effect or what is the goal?

Comment: Depends on how "strong" the measurement is. You can continuously monitor, but "weakly", in which case you can get dissipative dynamics governed by either a quantum master equation (with a Lindbladian) or by quantum state diffusion (via stochastic differential equations).

Comment: @TobiasFünke The unitary evolution contains hopping in the lattice. Numerically, I found that the measurement results in the localization of the particle. It appears that the localization length depends upon the rate of measurement. I'm looking for analytics to describe the dynamics.